# Strongly minimal covers

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, hypergraph, covering

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a hypergraph, that is $V$ is a set and $E\subseteq \mathcal{P}(V)$. We say that $C\subseteq E$ is a *cover* of $H$ if $\bigcup C = V$.

A cover $M\subseteq E$ is said to be *strongly minimal* if for every cover $C$ of $H$ we have $$\text{card}(M\setminus C)\leq \text{card}(C\setminus M).$$

Is there a hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ with the following properties?

1. $\bigcup E = V$;
2. $e\in E$ and $e'\subseteq e$ implies $e'\in E$;
3. for all $e\in E$ there is $m\in E$ such that $e\subseteq m$ and $m$ is maximal in $E$ with respect to set inclusion;
4. $H$ does not have a strongly minimal cover.

Comment: Are there finiteness assumptions? Or can $V$ be any set?

Comment: Good point. For finite $V$ there is always a strongly minimal cover in the setting above. So if there is an example without strongly minimal cover, $V$ must be infinite.

Comment: I think that the ***Question*** would be easier to read if stated without a hypergraph (without $\ H),\ $ simply about a family $\ E\ $ of subsets of $\ V$.

Comment: +1 for the *strong minimality* condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood something, but consider the following simple example.
Let $V=(0,\infty)$ and let the maximal edges be the (open) unit intervals, except $(0,1)$.
Any cover contains a sequence converging to $0$, so in fact there isn't any minimal cover at all.

**Update:** Noah asked whether there is an example where all edges are finite.
Here I give such an example.
Take $V=\{\frac 1i\mid i\in \mathbb N\} \cup \{-\frac 1i\mid i\in \mathbb N\}$.
For any $n\in \mathbb N$ we define two maximal edges.
The first is  $\{\frac 1i\mid i\le n\} \cup \{-\frac 1n\}$ and the second is $\{-\frac 1i\mid i\le n\} \cup \{\frac 1n\}$ (note that these are the same for $n=1$, but this won't matter).
Again there isn't any minimal cover.

Comment: Nice! (A set $\ V:=(0;\frac 32)\ $ would be a smaller example :-).

Comment: What happens if we require every element of $E$ to be finite? Then nothing like this works, but it's not clear that there isn't some other example.

Comment: At least one can modify @domotorp example by considering rationals only: $\ V:=(0;\infty)\cap\mathbb Q);\ $ and it's enough to consider as maximal edges the intervals $\ (a;a+1)\cap\mathbb Q\ $ such that $\ a>0\ $ and $\ a\in \mathbb Q.\ $ Thus domotorp's example becomes countable with countable many maximal edges.

Comment: @Noah: See the update.

Comment: The family $\big\{\{r\}\mid r\in\mathbb R\big\}$ is a minimal cover.

Comment: What about an example of a hypergraph without a strongly minimal cover when the hypergraph arises in the following way?  Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$.   Let the hypergraph $H$ have vertex set $V$ and edge set the set of cliques of $G$.

Comment: @Tri Isn't my example such? In the graph $G$ connect two vertices by an edge if and only if their distance is less than 1. The maximal edges will be exactly the open unit intervals.

Comment: @domotorp Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, ... be the terms of a convergent series of positive numbers that converges to, say, 1/1729.

Let $X_1=(0,1)$.
Let $X_2=(1-a_1,2-a_1)$.
Let $X_3=(2-a_1-a_2,3-a_1-a_2)$.
...

You get the idea.

I think this is a strongly minimal cover because if you remove, say, 42 of the $X$'s, they overlap so little, you have to replace them with at least 42 sets.  I have not proven this.

Comment: @Tri You are right, in this new version (0,1) will also be a clique!