# Minimal covers in hypergraphs with finite edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). We say that $C\subseteq E$ is a *cover* if $\bigcup C = V$. Let $H$ be a hypergraph with the following properties:

1. $\bigcup E = V$,
2. all members of $E$ are finite, and
3. $d,e\in E$ with $d\subseteq e$ implies $d=e$.

**Question.** Does this imply that there is a minimal cover $C_0$ (that is, $C_0$ has the property that for all $c\in C_0$ the set $C_0\setminus \{c\}$ is no longer a cover)?

Comment: While I agree with the correction V replaces E, I don't see condition 3 prescribing a minimal cover. In particular, cover half of V with three-sets, the other half with five-sets, and bridge the two halves with two-sets. This cover gives at least two smaller covers, and it might be possible to arrange no minimal cover through a clever selection.  Gerhard "That Doesn't Quite Cover It" Paseman, 2018.08.14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $V:=\omega\times\omega$ and $E=\{E_{n,m}:n,m\in\omega\}$ where $$E_{n,m}:=(\{0,\dots,n\}\times\{m\})\cup\{(2n,m+1)\}.$$ It seems that the hypergraph $(V,E)$ has no minimal cover.

A simplification of this example was suggested by Gerhard Paseman in his comment:
Just take $V=\mathbb Z$ and $E=\{E_n,F_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ where $E_n:=\{-2n\}\cup [0,n]$ and $F_n:=[-n,0]\cup\{2n\}$.

**Added in Edit.** I have just discovered that the Paseman's example is "isomorphic" to the example of @domotorp ([Strongly minimal covers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193352/strongly-minimal-covers?rq=1)) given in 2015 to a similar question of Dominic van der Zypen.

---

The question of Dominic van der Zypen has positive answer if the cardinalities of hyperedges are upper bounded by some number.

**Theorem.** For any $n\in\mathbb N$, any set $V$ and family $E\subset[V]^{\le n}$ with $\bigcup E=V$ there exists a minimal subfamily $C\subset E$ such that $\bigcup C=V$.

*Proof.* For $n=1$ the assertion is trivial. Assume that for some $n\ge 2$ we have proved that any family $E\subset [V]^{<n}$ with $\bigcup E=V$ contains a minimal subfamily $C\subset E$ with $\bigcup C=V$.

Take any family $E\subset [V]^{\le n}$ with $\bigcup E=V$. Using Zorn's lemma, choose a maximal disjoint subfamily $D\subset E$. If the set $W:=V\setminus\bigcup D$ is empty, then $D$ is a required minimal cover of $V$.

So, we assume that $W$ is not empty. By the maximality of $D$, each hyperedge  $e\in E\setminus D$ intersects the set $\bigcup D$, which implies that $E':=\{e\cap W:e\in E\setminus D\}\subset [W]^{<n}$. By the inductive assumption, the family $E'$ contains a minimal subfamily $C'\subset E'$ with $\bigcup C'=W$.

For every $c\in C'$ find a hyperedge $e_c\in E\setminus D$ such that $e_c\cap W=c$. Let $H:=\{e_c:c\in C'\}$ and $D':=\{e\in D:e\not\subset \bigcup H\}$. It can be shown that $C:=H\cup D'$ is a minimal subcover of $E$.

Comment: It looks like E_{n,2k} is minimal by looking at odd values of m.  Gerhard "Seems Pretty Minimal At Odds" Paseman, 2018.08.16.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Ups! This is a small problem, which is corrected now. Thank you for noticing it.

Comment: Indeed, by mirroring the construction you can let m range over a two element set instead of over omega.  Gerhard "2N Is A Nice Touch" Paseman, 2018.08.16.

Comment: After your nice acknowledgement, it occurs to me that we have folded over the integers.  I will let you do the formulation over Z.  Gerhard "This Makes It Even Simpler" Paseman, 2018.08.16.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman So simple!

Comment: Very nice Taras, and thanks @GerhardPaseman for your simplification!

Comment: This additional theorem of yours with a universal upper bound for the size of the edges is very nice! (Unfortunately I can only upvote once.)

Comment: @TarasBanakh You are very welcome. I write some more in an e-mail message directed to the address you give on your homepage

Comment: I posted a slightly generalized version of your argument here as an answer to my question [Graphs with minimum degree $\delta(G)\lt\aleph_0$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324504/graphs-with-minimum-degree-deltag-lt-aleph-0). I hope you don't mind, and I hope I got it right.

Comment: @bof Thank you.