# Strongly minimal covers for clique hypergraphs of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, hypergraph

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cliq{Cliq}$A *hypergraph* $H$ is a pair consisting of a set $V$ of *vertices* and a family of subsets of $V$ called *edges*.
One class of examples is obtained by taking a graph $G=(V,E)$ with set of vertices $V$ and set of edges $E$ where $H=(V,\Cliq (G) )$.  Here $e\in \Cliq(G)$ if and only if for all $v,w\in e$ such that $v\ne w$ we have $\{v,w\}\in E$.

If $H=(V,F)$ is a hypergraph, a *cover* is a subset $C$ of $F$ such that $\bigcup C=V$.  The cover is *strongly minimal* if for any cover $D$, $|C\setminus D|\le|D\setminus C|$.

Please give an example of a hypergraph stemming from the cliques of a graph as above that has no strongly minimal cover.

A related post with a nice example by domotorp is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193352/strongly-minimal-covers).

Edit: I had an incorrect definition of "cover" before. Thanks to Mikhail Tikhomirov for leading me to look at it again.

Comment: I assume "a family $C$ of subsets of $F$" means a collection of hyperedges, rather than a collection of hyperedge sets ("subsets of $F$")?

Comment: I have edited the definition of "cover." Thanks.

Comment: You are asking whether every graph has a strongly minimal covering by cliques. An equivalent (perhaps more natural) question is whether every graph has a strongly minimal cover by **anticliques** (independent sets). It seems clear that every **locally finite** graph has a strongly minimal cover by anticliques.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll have to think about why it's clear. ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify your comment @bof?

Comment: @bof I think Dominic van der Zypen means (at least, I mean): What is the proof?  I'm guessing it is some application of something like Rado's Selection Lemma.

Comment: **(I)** Let $G$ be a graph and let $f:V(G)\to\mathbb N$ be a proper coloring of $G$. Suppose that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, there is an induced subgraph $G_n$ of $G$ such that $\chi(G_n)=n$ and $f[V(G_n)]=\{1,2,\dots n\}$. Then the color classes of $f$ are a strongly minimal cover of $V$ by anticliques. **(II)** If $G$ is a locally finite graph with infinite chromatic number, then such a coloring $f$ can be constructed. @Tri

Comment: If instead of $G$, you consider $\bar G$, then a cover becomes a proper coloring, and the strongly minimal condition translates to that no union of some color classes can be recolored with fewer colors. I think it's a good idea to look at some old papers dealing with similar constructions, like https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1968-04.pdf.

Comment: @domotorp Thanks. I will try to see the connection between the Erdos-Hajnal paper and this question. (I vaguely recall that Shelah showed something funny happens at $\aleph_{\omega+1}$.)

Answer (score 1):

I can prove the following weaker statement, which was not true in the other version:
Every hypergraph stemming from the cliques of a graph has a minimal cover, where I define a cover as minimal if the union of no two of its hyperedges is a hyperedge.

The proof follows from Zorn's lemma.
Define a poset $P$ on the covers such that $C<D$ if for every clique $c\in C$ there is a clique $d\in D$ such that $c\subset d$.
$P$ satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma, as in any chain $C_1<C_2<\dots$ we can consider all clique-chains $c_1\subset c_2\subset\ldots$ where $c_i\in C_i$, and let $C=\{c\mid c=\cup c_i$ for some such clique-chain$\}$.
A maximal element of $P$, guaranteed to exist by Zorn's lemma, is necessarily a minimal cover.

Comment: @bof https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193352/strongly-minimal-covers?rq=1#comment1084418_193494

Comment: I added my interpretation of minimal to my answer.

Comment: Instead of defining a partial order on the covers, you can simply define a partial order on the cliques themselves, and use Zorn's lemma to show that every vertex is in a maximal clique. This shows that the set of all maximal cliques is a cover. Of course it's minimal, since the union of two maximal cliques is notv a clique.

Comment: @Tri Is there a definition of "minimal cover" in that other question?

Comment: @bof Probably not. My definition of "minimal" is with respect to set-inclusion.

Comment: We can call this property 2-cover-free instead of minimal, if you wish, the point is, that the other construction had this property, and for this question no such thing can work.